# How "make" reads/resolves Makefile with percentage-matched target vs. explicit?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I thought I understood that `%` pattern matching:

```
%.o : %.c
    #...
```

...was equivalent to "explicitly" writing the targets' rules:

```
f1.o : f1.c
    #...

f2.o : f2.c
    #...
```

(assuming those are the only `.c` files)

---

I also know that writing multiple rules for the same explicit target results in the rule being overwritten by the last defined rule:

```
r :
    #1

r :
    #2
```

(`make` outputs `#2`)

---

So, how exactly does `make` resolve the Makefile below?

```
foo : bar

bar :
    #bar

% : %.c
    #%
```

When `bar.c` is the only `.c` file in the directory (or there's none), it outputs:

> #bar

If there's only `foo` and `foo.c` (and the Makefile):

> #bar
> #%

I wasn't sure what to expect when there was a `bar.c` file, but I thought when there wasn't that the only "command" being run would be `#bar`.

### So, how are these rules/dependencies being resolved like this?

---

The reason that I'm interested is because this implicit/explicit "double-rule" syntax seems essential to understanding how `-M` and `include` work to automate header dependencies, for example:

```
a.out: main.o
    g++ main.o

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $< -c

main.o: main.cpp foo.h # <-- what *.d files look like
```

...causes desired behaviour like:

```
a.out: main.o
    g++ main.o

main.o: main.cpp foo.h
    g++ $< -c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought I understood that % pattern matching ... was equivalent to "explicitly" writing the targets ... (assuming those are the only .c files)

That's not right.

A pattern rule is a *template* that tells make how it CAN build a target.  Pattern rules are only used if there's no explicit rule for that target already.  A pattern rule doesn't say "go find all files that match this pattern and create explicit rules for them".  It says, "if you find you need to build a target but you don't have any explicit rule already, and the target matches this pattern, then here's how you can build it".

For example, if you have a makefile that contains ONLY pattern rules, even if those pattern rules match existing files, and you just type `make`, you'll get a message that make has nothing to do.  That's because you've not asked make to build anything, you just told make HOW to build something.

> I also know that writing multiple rules for the same explicit target results in the rule being overwritten by the last defined rule

Of course, you will get a warning if you do this about overwriting an existing recipe.

It's important to understand that you can have as many different lines adding new prerequisites to a target as you like.  It's not until you create a recipe that you have created an explicit rule.  Until then, there's no actual rule that matches the target.

Comment: An explicit rule must have a recipe.  If there's no recipe, it's not an explicit rule.  See my last paragraph above.

Answer (score 0):

On top of `MadScientist`'s expert answer, I thought I'd explain how it applies to both outputs for the Makefile (which might be useful for `make` beginners like me):

```
foo: bar

bar :
    #bar

% : %.c
    #%
```

### #bar

---

When there's no `bar` file:

```
bar :
    #bar
```

...then `bar` is a "non-file" (phony) target. A phony target with no prerequisites always executes the recipe - as opposed to a file target where no prerequisites means that the target never has its recipe executed (not sure why this doesn't result in warnings). So, ironically, when there's no `bar` file, we see `#bar` output, otherwise we don't.

### #%

---

As MadScientist says in his answer, `% : %.c` can never match `bar`/`bar.c` because there's an explicit rule for `bar` (ie. one with a recipe). However, we can use the recipe in

```
% : %.c
    #%
```

... if we have the files `foo`/`foo.c`. This is because `foo : bar` isn't an explicit rule (has no recipe). The Makefile becomes equivalent to:

```
foo: bar

bar :
    #bar

foo : foo.c
    #%
```

...which is equivalent to:

```
foo: bar foo.c
    #%

bar :
    #bar
```

So `make` will output `#%` if there's no `bar` file, or if `foo`'s timestamp is older than either `bar` or `foo.c`.

### #bar

### #%

---

To work out the combination of files we need to get both `#bar` and `#%`, we use our logic from the `#bar` section (above) which is simpler: We cannot have a `bar` file. Looking at the `#%` section, we see that if we have no `bar` file then we still need both `foo` and `foo.c` files (but timestamps won't matter). So the directory will be: `foo`, `foo.c`, `Makefile`, plus any other file except for `bar`.