# Why is Makefile not including the header?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to make a library for my project but I am very very new to Makefiles. I tried several configurations and adding `-I` but none worked.

I have the following three:

```
libft/
../includes/
....libft.h
../lst
....ft_lstnew.c
....ft_lstadd_front.c
....ft_lstadd_back.c
....  [...]
../src
....ft_isalpha.c
....ft_isalnum.c
....  [...]
```

And the following makefile:

```
NAME=libft.a

LIBSO=libft.so

CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror

SRC_DIR=src/

BONUS_DIR=lst/

OBJ_DIR=obj/

SRC_FILES=  ft_bzero.c      \
            ft_isalmun.c    \
            ft_isalpha.c    \
            ft_isascii.c    \
            ft_isdigit.c    \
            ft_isprint.c    \
            ft_memchr.c     \
            ft_memcpy.c     \
            ft_memmove.c    \
            ft_memset.c     \
            ft_strchr.c     \
            ft_strlcat.c    \
            ft_strlcpy.c    \
            ft_strlen.c     \
            ft_strncmp.c    \
            ft_strrchr.c    \
            ft_tolower.c    \
            ft_toupper.c    

BONUS_FILES=ft_lstadd_back.c    \
            ft_lstadd_front.c   \
            ft_lstdelone.c      \
            ft_lstclear.c       \
            ft_lstiter.c        \
            ft_lstlast.c        \
            ft_lstmap.c         \
            ft_lstnew.c         \
            ft_lstsize.c        

SRC_PATH=$(addprefix $(SRC_DIR), $(SRC_FILES))

BONUS_PATH=$(addprefix $(BONUS_DIR), $(BONUS_FILES))

SRC_NAMES=$(SRC_FILES:.c=.o)

BONUS_NAMES=$(BONUS_FILES:.c=.o)

SRC_PATH_O=$(addprefix $(SRC_DIR), $(SRC_NAMES))

BONUS_PATH_O=$(addprefix $(BONUS_DIR), $(BONUS_NAMES))

HDR_NAME=libft.h

HDR_DIR=includes/

HDR= $(addprefix $(HDR_DIR),$(HDR_NAME))

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(SRC_PATH_O)
    ar rc $@ $<
    ranlib $@

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir $@

$(OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c $(HDR_NAME)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I $(HDR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    
fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

And I keep getting this each time I type `make` on the terminal:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror   -c -o src/ft_bzero.o src/ft_bzero.c
src/ft_bzero.c:1:10: fatal error: libft.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "libft.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: src/ft_bzero.o] Error 1
```

Am I missing something? It's literally my first time.

Comment: You could type `#include "include/libft.h"`, but mostly we tell the compiler to look there by the following flag: `-I include` (the `-I` stands for `include`, which adds the given prefix to any `#include` if a file isn't found without it).

Comment: By the way, you definitely want to auto-generate those file names.

Comment: @Elliott auto-generate? how?

Comment: Well, for source files you can do `SOURCES := $(shell find src -type f -name *.c)`, same idea for the rest.

Comment: @Elliott thing is I already added ``-I`` but keep getting the error

Comment: In which directory is the Makefile?

Comment: Note that `-I $(HDR)` in your compile command expands (I think) to `-I includes/libft.h` -- probably not what you intended.  You can check the values of your variables with something like [`$(info HDR=[$(HDR)])`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-printing-messages) etc.

Comment: @Elliott it is on libft

Comment: change `-I $(HDR)` to `-I includes`

Comment: @Elliott nope, also tried with includes/libft.h

Comment: Okay, back to basics: [provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're having (a few files, a one or two directors, and a short makefile). [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69065221/how-make-reads-resolves-makefile-with-percentage-matched-target-vs-explicit) of how I asked a similar question about Makefiles.

Comment: @Elliott that's the full make file. I can share the repo if that is easier

Comment: Well, it's neither minimal nor reproducible in its current state.

Comment: @Elliott added...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238567/discussion-between-elliott-and-miguelp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're missing some things.

First, look at the command line make shows:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror   -c -o src/ft_bzero.o src/ft_bzero.c
```

Note that the output here is not right for the recipe of the pattern rule you created: there's no `-I` option, and the object file is being written to `src/` not `obj/`.

From this you should realize that your pattern rule is not being used at all, and instead make is using its built-in rule for building object files.

Why isn't your pattern rule being used?  Let's look at it:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c $(HDR_NAME)
```

what is this after variable expansion?

```
obj/%.o: src/%.c libft.h
```

This pattern (like all patterns) can only match if ALL the prerequisites either already exist or can be built.  The `src/%.c` exists, after the pattern substitution.  What about `libft.h`?  No, that doesn't exist.  What *does* exist is `includes/libft.h` but that's not the same thing.

So, this rule fails to match and make goes back to using its default rules.

If you want to say that every object file depends on that header, you have to use the correct path to the header file when you write the pattern.

Next, this is wrong:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I $(HDR)
```

What is `$(HDR)`?  It's the name of the file: `include/libft.h`.  You don't include header file names with `-I`; you include *directories* that headers are looked for in.  So you need `$(HDR_DIR)` here instead.

Comment: If you want to avoid confusion with built-in rules you can turn them off by using the `-r` option when you run make: e.g. `make -r`.  If you do that and your pattern rule doesn't match you'll get an error saying "No rule to make obj/xxx.o", rather than some other rule being used.

Comment: How can I fix it? I replaced HDR for HDR_DIR and still got the error

Comment: How can you fix which problem?  Where did you replace HDR for HDR_DIR?

Comment: the error. I switched ```$(OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c $(HDR_NAME)    
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I $(HDR_DIR)```

Comment: You didn't do anything about the first problem: your rule is not written correctly.  You only fixed the second problem (starting with _Next, this is wrong_).  I explained what was wrong with using `$(HDR_NAME)` as the prerequisite: that file doesn't exist.